# Reverse Polish Calculator Exception Handling in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, python-3.x, exception, rpn

So I've almost finished this program but I can't figure out how to put in proper exception handling based on these rules:

> You must handle the following situations (errors):
>
> Too many operators (+ - / *)
>
> Too many operands (doubles)
>
> Division by zero

### Prompt

For this assignment, you are to write a program, which will calculate the results of Reverse Polish expressions that are provided by the user.

You must use a linked list to maintain the stack for this program (array implementations of the stack will not receive full credit).

You must handle the following situations (errors):
Too many operators (+ - / *)
Too many operands (doubles)
Division by zero

The program will take in a Polish expression that separates the operators and operands by a single space, and terminates the expression with a new line.

The program will continue to take and evaluate expressions until the user enters a zero (0) on a line by itself followed by a new line.

Your sample output should show the handling of all the error conditions as well as make use of all of the operators.

Sample IO: (note: formatting of output isn’t a critical issue)

```
Input    Output
10 15 +  25
10 15 -  -5
2.5 3.5 +    6 (or 6.0)
10 0 /   Error: Division by zero
10 20 * /    Error: Too many operators
12 20 30 /   Error: Too many operands
-10 -30 -    20
100 10 50 25 / * - -2 /  -40
```

### Program

Here's what I got so far:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

class LinkedStack:
  #LIFO Stack implementation using a singly linked list for storage.

  #-------------------------- nested _Node class --------------------------
  class _Node:
    #Lightweight, nonpublic class for storing a singly linked node.
    __slots__ = '_element', '_next' # streamline memory usage

    def __init__(self, element, next): # initialize node’s fields
        self._element = element # reference to user’s element
        self._next = next # reference to next node

  def __init__(self):
    #Create an empty stack.
    self._head = None # reference to the head node
    self._size = 0 # number of stack elements

  @property
  def __len__(self):
    #Return the number of elements in the stack.
    return self._size

  def is_empty(self):
    #Return True if the stack is empty.
    return self._size == 0

  def push(self, e):
    #Add element e to the top of the stack.
    self._head = self._Node(e, self._head) # create and link a new node
    self._size += 1

  def pop(self):
    i = self._head._element
    self._head = self._head._next
    self._size -= 1
    return i

ls = LinkedStack()

# Changing the operators to behave like functions via lambda
# Needed for stack push and pop rules down below
# '+' : (lambda x, y: x + y) is same as def '+' (x,y): return x + y  
operators = {
  '+' : (lambda x, y: x + y),
  '-' : (lambda x, y: y - x),
  '*' : (lambda x, y: x * y),
  '/' : (lambda x, y: y / x)
}


def evaluate(tokens):
  # Evaluate RPN expression (given as string of tokens)
  for i in tokens:
    if i in operators:
        ls.push(operators[i](ls.pop(), ls.pop()))
    else:
      ls.push(float(i))
  return ls.pop()


def main():
  while True:
    print("Input the expression: ", end='')

    # Read line by line from stdin + tokenize line + evaluates line
    tokens = re.split(" *", sys.stdin.readline().strip())

    # Output the stack
    print("Stack: ",tokens)

    # Output result
    if not tokens:
      break
    print("Result: ",evaluate(tokens),'\n')

# Call main
if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

### Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: Look at a [Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) implementation in [Python](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/Shunting-yard_algorithm#Python)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose some input has `n` numbers and `o` operators. It appears that `o == n-1` for valid input. So perhaps you can assert that `o == n-1`. If there are too many operators then perhaps `o > n-1` or too few, `o < n-1`. To detect division by zero you might check the "right-hand operand" given a request for division, and assert that it is not zero.